# how to show row data in column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case-when

I am beginner in T-SQL, I am stuck in a problem in which a row must be produce every day & a table which consists of following columns "DATE","PRICE","CATEGORY 1", "CATEGORY 2". The output must create the column(Combination of "CATEGORY 1", "CATEGORY 2") & show the price. If price is not available than null should be shown. Below is the result which I need to produce

```
TABLE
-----------------------------------------------
DATE      | PRICE    | CATEGORY 1 | CATEGORY 2
-----------------------------------------------
20171215    285            Books      Non-Fiction
20171212    390            Gaming     PlayStation 4
20171213    40             Antiques   collectables
```

OUTPUT

```
DATE       | Books- Non-Fiction | Gaming - PlayStation 4 | Antiques - collectables  
20171212          NULL                     390                   NULL
20171213          NULL                     NULL                  40
20171215          285                      NULL                  NULL
```

is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: what is your DBMS?

Comment: I am using MSSQL

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use *condition aggregate function*

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   DATE INT,
   PRICE INT,
   [CATEGORY 1] VARCHAR(50),
   [CATEGORY 2] VARCHAR(50)

);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (20171215,285,'Books','Non-Fiction');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (20171212,390,'Gaming','PlayStation 4');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (20171213,40 ,'Antiques','collectables');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DATE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [CATEGORY 1] = 'Books' and [CATEGORY 2] = 'Non-Fiction'  THEN PRICE end) 'Books- Non-Fiction ',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [CATEGORY 1] = 'Gaming' and [CATEGORY 2] = 'PlayStation 4'  THEN PRICE  end) 'Gaming - PlayStation 4',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [CATEGORY 1] = 'Antiques' and [CATEGORY 2] = 'collectables'  THEN PRICE  end) 'Antiques - collectables'    
FROM T
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e4d57/2/0)**:

```
|     DATE | Books- Non-Fiction  | Gaming - PlayStation 4 | Antiques - collectables |
|----------|---------------------|------------------------|-------------------------|
| 20171212 |              (null) |                    390 |                  (null) |
| 20171213 |              (null) |                 (null) |                      40 |
| 20171215 |                 285 |                 (null) |                  (null) |
```

Comment: is there any way to auto generate single row every day?

Comment: What do you mean `auto generate single row every day`? Is there any example?

Comment: @D-Shih When there's an entry for more than one category on the same date you end up with another row since the results aren't grouped. Esperento57 has addressed this in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT DATE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [CATEGORY 1] = 'Books' and [CATEGORY 2] = 'Non-Fiction'  THEN PRICE ELSE null end) 'Books- Non-Fiction',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [CATEGORY 1] = 'Gaming' and [CATEGORY 2] = 'PlayStation 4'  THEN PRICE ELSE null  end) 'Gaming - PlayStation 4',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [CATEGORY 1] = 'Antiques' and [CATEGORY 2] = 'collectables'  THEN PRICE ELSE NULL end) 'Antiques - collectables'     
FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE
```

Comment: Can I do the sum of price which are on same date?

Comment: It's the result of my query, sum by date and by type of categories